# Confusion about a result in Pierce's book Associative Algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, algebras

I am confused about two Lemmas in the book *Associative Algebras* by R.Pierce (pages 43-44).

[image]
[image]
[image]
In **Lemma d**, since each right ideal of a can be considered an algebra over $A$ then if $N$ is a minimal right ideal of $A$, by **lemma a (vi)**, $N$ is also a minimal ideal of some $N_i$.

However by definition of minimility of both ideals we get that $N=N_i$.

Where is my mistake ? Why do we only have an isomorphism between the two ideals ?

Comment: Because  $N_i$ is not a sub-algebra of $A$. it is just a minimal right ideal. (It doesnot have the identity  $1$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since each right ideal of a can be considered an algebra over $$

An algebra over $A$? In what sense? Algebras are usually not defined over noncommutative rings, and that is what your context allows for.

> However by definition of minimility of both ideals we get that $=_$

You could only get equality if one was contained in the other, but there is no such guarantee.  You can at best say they're isomorphic.

For example, in $A=M_2(\mathbb R)$, let $N_1$ be the subset with zeros on the bottom row, and $N_2$ be the subset with zeros on the top row.  Both are minimal right ideals, unequal as subsets, but isomorphic to each other (and to every other minimal right ideal.)